# how to group record counts by hour of day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Here are my models:

Interaction.rb

```
class Interaction < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :report
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :fb_user
  has_one :fb_page
```

Report.rb

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  has_many :page_stats,
    dependent: :destroy
  has_many :interactions,
    dependent: :destroy
  has_many :fb_users,
    through: :interactions
  has_one :fb_page,
    foreign_key: :fb_id,
    primary_key: :fb_page_id
  has_many :posts,
    dependent: :destroy
```

FbUser.rb

```
class FbUser < ActiveRecord::Base

  self.primary_key = "id"
  has_many :interactions
```

What I would like to do is group Interactions by the hour of day that they occurred. I'm looking for a hash of 1-24 (hours of the day, UTC) and group the Interaction counts by when they occurred.

Here's an example return value:

{{1 => 23}, {2 => 7}, {n => x}}

Basically, for hour 1, there were 23 interactions, for hour 2, there were 7. I want to do this for each 1 through 24 hours of the day.

Interaction has a column called "interaction_time" which is when the interaction occurred. thanks

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: postgres...so I guess sql?

Comment: Modified my answer for postgres

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For postgres,

```
Interaction
.select('EXTRACT(HOUR from interaction_time)')
.group('EXTRACT(HOUR FROM interaction_time)')
.order('EXTRACT(HOUR from interaction_time)')
.count
```

Comment: this works well although i'd like to order the results by interaction_time starting from 0-23. however i keep getting an error like "PG::GroupingError: ERROR: column "interactions.interaction_time" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"

Comment: @Matthew Berman: Modified my answer to include order. Tested it and seems to work

Comment: For MySQL try this `ATransaction.where('recordTime >= ?', 1.month.ago).group("hour(recordTime)").count`

Answer (score 1):

so... in your interaction model create a method:

```
def hour
  self.interaction_time.to_date.strftime('%H')
end
```

that will return your models from 0-23.  to group them:

```
@user = FbUser.find(params[:id])
hours_of_day = @user.interactions.group_by(&:hour)
```

play with that array now... `hours_of_day.keys`, hours_of_day.values`,`.size`, etc.

the key should be the hour, then the value should be an array of the different interactions that took place in that hour

```
hours_of_day.each do |key, value|
  puts key
  puts value.size
end
```

something like that...